# Write Spark DF to a flat file on local pc from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark

I need to write a Spark DF to a flat file on my local PC.
I'm executing my program on Scala IDE on Eclipse (again on my local PC)
This is the command I use:

```
df.coalesce(1).rdd.saveAsTextFile(s"file:///C:/myfile.csv")
```

It creates *C:\myfile.csv_temporary\0_temporary\attempt_20180208105406_0016_m_000000_819* foder and even *part-00000* file in it, but the file is empty

This is the error message I'm getting on the console:

> Exception in task 0.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 819)
>   java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 C:\myfile.csv_temporary\0_temporary\attempt_20180208105406_0016_m_000000_819\part-00000*

Comment: its a permission issue in c:

Comment: I created a separate folder and made sure the Permissions are set to Full control. Same issue. Not sure if something special needs to be done for Scala IDE to allow access to this folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try set HADOOP_HOME to the subdirectory with bin\winuitls.exe